# Checking if list in Python dataframe contains specific value while ignoring NaNs

Tags: python, pandas, list

Let's assume my dataframe's second column contains lists of integers:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"col_1":[1,2,3,4,5],"col_2":[[1,2],np.nan,[3,5,9],[2],[8,5]],"col_3":np.nan})
```

Output:

```
   col_1      col_2  col_3
0      1     [1, 2]    NaN
1      2        NaN    NaN
2      3  [3, 5, 9]    NaN
3      4        [2]    NaN
4      5     [8, 5]    NaN
```

I'd like to insert a `1` in column 3 if the int in column 1 can be found in in the list of ints in column 2:

```
   col_1      col_2  col_3
0      1     [1, 2]    1
1      2        NaN    NaN
2      3  [3, 5, 9]    1
3      4        [2]    NaN
4      5     [8, 5]    1
```

I was trying to solve it like that:

```
for i in range(0,len(df)):
    if df["col_1"][i] in df["col_2"][i]:
        df["col_3"][i]=1
```

This gave me `TypeError: argument of type 'float' is not iterable` because of the `NaN` in the column 2 and I couldn't work out a way to deal with it.

(I've tried to solve this using a diffent solution based on `.isin` but this wouldn't work because `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'isin'`.)

I then had the idea to replace all the `NaN` in col_2 with a `0` so that my inital for loop would be able to run through. There are no `0` in col_1 and will never be, so I'd be fine with that solution because this won't lead to wrong matches in col_3. To this end,

```
df.loc[df["col_2"].isnull(), "col_2"] = 0
```

is not enough because the `if in` can't deal with ints: `TypeError: argument of type 'int' is not iterable`. I would need the `0` do be inserted as an element of a list, but you can't just use `=[0]` instead. I've tried different things based on `.at` because it should be able to insert lists into cells, but I couldn't work it out.

Thank you in advance for any advice!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can filter out NaNs with `if-else` with `x['col_2'] == x['col_2']` because `NaN != NaN` is `False`, alsofor convert `True`s values to `1` is used `map` by dictionary, `False` values are not in dict, so returned `NaN`s:

```
f = lambda x: x['col_1'] in x['col_2'] if x['col_2'] == x['col_2'] else np.nan
df['col_3'] = df.apply(f, 1).map({True:1})
print (df)
   col_1      col_2  col_3
0      1     [1, 2]    1.0
1      2        NaN    NaN
2      3  [3, 5, 9]    1.0
3      4        [2]    NaN
4      5     [8, 5]    1.0
```

Or use [`DataFrame.dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) for remove NaNs rows and after assign back new column are added removed `NaN`s:

```
f = lambda x: x['col_1'] in x['col_2']
df['col_3'] = df.dropna(subset=['col_1', 'col_2']).apply(f, 1).map({True:1})
print (df)
   col_1      col_2  col_3
0      1     [1, 2]    1.0
1      2        NaN    NaN
2      3  [3, 5, 9]    1.0
3      4        [2]    NaN
4      5     [8, 5]    1.0
```

Comment: Thank you so much @jezrael, this is like magic to me. While your second suggestion intuitively makes more sense to me (given my python level) I still went with the first one because it also works for those cases where col_2 doesn't contain any values. I didn't know I had these cases (I have like 20 of these columns) but found out thanks to your code.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
s=df.dropna(subset=['col_2','col_1'])
df['new']=pd.DataFrame(s.col_2.tolist(),index=s.index).isin(df.col_1).sum(1).loc[lambda x : x!=0]
df
   col_1      col_2  col_3  new
0      1     [1, 2]    NaN  1.0
1      2        NaN    NaN  NaN
2      3  [3, 5, 9]    NaN  1.0
3      4        [2]    NaN  NaN
4      5     [8, 5]    NaN  1.0
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your time @WeNYoBen. Your solution works like a charm and delivers instant results even for more than a million rows per column, but i went with jezrael's one because that one was easier for me to modify looping through a series of columns. Instead of actually using "col_2" I'm inserting the titles of the columns from another dataframe: `df[str(cols["titles"][i])]` and then looping through the `i`s. Still: Thanks a lot!